# if ! Not working for StringBuilder android

Tags: android

My code reads a .txt file and checks if it does not have "yoloswag" in it. And displays the string in a dialog if it doesn't.

```
private void display() {
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard, "broadcast.txt");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    if (!text.equals("yoloswag")) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("BROADCAST").setMessage(text).create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alertDialog.show();
    } else {
        // don't show
    }
}
```

but the problem is, it always displays the dialog regardless of if the .txt file has "yoloswag" in it or not. Where am I wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will always be false because you need to call toString() method on the StringBuilder

```
if (!text.toString().equals("yoloswag"))
```

Also, for each line you are reading, you are adding a "\n" at the end, so even if the file contains "yoloswag", the StringBuilder you produce is "yoloswag\n", the reason why they are never equal.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @joey Then you're not really using SO in the way it was intended. Which answer to accept is up to you, though. Generally it should be the most useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
    String result = text.toString();
    if (!result.contains("yoloswag")) { 
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("BROADCAST")
        .setMessage(text).create();alertDialog.getWindow().setType( WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT); 
         alertDialog.show(); 
   } else { 
      // don't show 
   }
```